# Looking to do conditional formatting based on a variable cell

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

The plan is to have a variable cell to tell the conditional formatting how many non blanks to colour. I.e. I would like to colour only the first 5 non blanks within a data range.

The other conditional formatting I wish to have is the same but rather than going top down I want it to go from the bottom of the range up. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional formatting for that, using a formula that calculates the number of empty cells from a start cell to the current cell.

The following formula assumes that the cell that tells how many blank cells should be coloured is cell A1 and the data is in column C:

```
=AND(C1="",COUNTBLANK(C$1:C1)<=$A$1)
```

Note that the range `C$1:C1` contains a $ for the start row, not for the end row. With that, the `COUNTBLANK` will count the number of empty cells starting from row 1 to the actual row.

To use it "backwards", you need to know which is the last row of your data. In the following example, row 20 is assumed:

```
=AND(C1="",COUNTBLANK(C1:C$20)<=$A$1)
```

**Update**
Misread the original post. To mark the first non-blank cells, use formula

```
=AND(C1<>"",COUNTA(C$1:C1)<=$A$1)
```

Similarly, to mark from bottom, use

```
=AND(C1<>"",COUNTA(C1:C$20)<=$A$1)
```

Comment: Much appreciated but unfortunately these formulas are not quite doing what I want.
Can there formulas be altered to colour non blanks rather than the blanks?
I tried altering them to use counta rather than countblank but still no luck.

Comment: @FuntThomas - Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: @J.Counter: See my update. CountA is the right function, but you need to modify the first part of the `AND` also

Comment: Thanks for your help. The formula from the bottom up is working perfectly.

Comment: However the formula from the top down is not working for some reason. No formatting takes place at all. =AND(D2<>"",COUNTA(D$2:D84)<=D$89) is the formula i'm trying and is not working. Whereas =AND(D2<>"",COUNTA(D2:D$84)<=D$90) is working>

Comment: Any solutions buddy?

Comment: No. Was working for me and I don't have your setup and data. May have different reasons: Typo in the Cond.Formatting Formula, D89 is empty, another Cond. Formatting overwrites the rule... Try the formula in an empty column and check if it show TRUE or FALSE as expected

Comment: Yeah I tried that already but it doesn't work, even when no other formatting is in the column not sure why. Data is in D89 too